# Passing 2d arrays into a function with variable as array size?

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, parameter-passing

So I'm writing a function to copy a 2d array into another one, like this:

```
void copyTable(int val, char table[][16], char tableNew[][16]){
    for(int y = 0; y< val; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x<val; x++ ){
            table[x][y]=tableNew[x][y];
        }
    }    
}
```

This compiles, but what I really need to be able to do is instead of 16 have a variable so that the function can be used with any size array, like this:

```
int num;

void copyTable(int val, char table[][num], char tableNew[][num]){
    for(int y = 0; y< val; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x<val; x++ ){
            table[x][y]=tableNew[x][y];
        }
    }    
}
```

I get the errors:

```
main.cpp:14:41: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token
 void copyTable(int val, char table[][num], char tableNew[][num]){
                                         ^
main.cpp:14:42: error: expected ')' before ',' token
 void copyTable(int val, char table[][num], char tableNew[][num]){
                                          ^
main.cpp:14:44: error: expected unqualified-id before 'char'
 void copyTable(int val, char table[][num], char tableNew[][num]){
```

Where line 14 is "void copyTable(..."

Comment: Consider dynamic memory allocation with `new`

Answer (score 0):

The C compiler needs to know what `table[1][0]` means when using the array, so it needs all but the first size to be a specified constant.

The solution is to pass in an extra variable giving the second dimension of the array. Because the double-array notation can only be used when the second dimension is a known constant, you will have to do your own indexing. `table[2][3]` becomes `table[2 * num + 3]`. Also note that the array can be passed into the function as a pointer, and this pointer can be treated like a single-dimensional array.

```
void copyTable(int val, char *table, char *tableNew, int num){
    for(int y = 0; y < val; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < val; x++){
            table[x * num + y] = tableNew[x * num + y];
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this..

```
void copyTo(int x, int y, int** destination, int** source)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            destination[i][j] = source[i][j];
    return;
}
```

Then allocate memory for your tables as such:

```
int x,y;    

//variable length tables
int** A = new int*[x];
int** B = new int*[x];

for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    A[i] = new int[y];
    B[i] = new int[y];
}
...

//call function as
copyTo(x,y,B,A);

...
```